# Inverted Bake Normal Map

Tags: uv, normal-map

I am trying to bake a high poly to low poly model but this results in an inverted normal map

[image: Problem]

Comment: Have you checked that your normals on the High poly mesh are facing the right way? Aslo it might help to bake with a cage object to make sure the normals are bake the right way around.

Comment: I've checked, it is facing the right way

Comment: Your Image Texture needs to be set to Non-Color and not sRGB. If it still doesn't fix your problem please share your file with the images packed

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_0EwHMN0VnwjkSYSFyB8XanwI6Ogeyw/view?usp=share_link